# Redirection htacces except words

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all urls starting with: 
http://domain1/maisons-et-chalets/

Except urls ending with: ".html" and "Bamako". Example:

- http://domain1/maisons-et-chalets/maison-duplex-a-vendre-ou-a-louer-sebenikoro.html
- http://domain1/maisons-et-chalets/bamako

I put in place the following rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/maisons-et-chalets/*[^(.html)]$ http://domain2/type-immobilier/maison-villa/
```

It does not work.

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)^/maisons-et-chalets/(?!(.+\.html$|bamako$)) http://domain2/type-immobilier/maison-villa/
```